# How to safely reset corrupted Zookeeper server

Tags: apache-zookeeper, paxos

Zookeeper admin guide say the following:

> A server might not be able to read its database and fail to come up
>   because of some file corruption in the transaction logs of the
>   ZooKeeper server. You will see some IOException on loading ZooKeeper
>   database.
>
> in such a case, **make sure all the other servers in your ensemble are
>   up and working**. Use "**stat**" command on the command port to see if
>   they are in good health. After you have verified that all the other
>   servers of the ensemble are up, you can go ahead and clean the
>   database of the corrupt server. Delete all the files in
>   datadir/version-2 and datalogdir/version-2/. Restart the server.

How do I know from the information below when it's safe for current Zookeeper Server to restart with an empty state ?

For follower

```
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/1891
Received: 334210
Sent: 333068
Connections: 23
Outstanding: 0
Zxid: 0x59000712a0
Mode: follower
Node count: 281908
```

For leader

```
Latency min/avg/max: 0/0/1829
Received: 9258940
Sent: 9252915
Connections: 829
Outstanding: 2
Zxid: 0x5900074b05
Mode: leader
Node count: 281909
```

Also would trying to connect to current ensemble and try to create a session using Zookeeper client library also be a good way to verify the ensemble currently have quorum and is **safe** to join with empty state?